# create android Sliding Menu like Flipkart(IOS App)

Tags: android, menu, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer, android-sliding

I need sliding menu which look like as flipkart application(IOS).please refer me any links or any idea.i checked with ios flipkart application.

Comment: Please have a look https://github.com/mohammedDehairy/MDMenuViewController